how to migrate azurerm to az powershell
i got s360 item for migration of azure rm to az powershell with some subscription in providers like example https://management.azure.com:xxx/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxx-xxxxx-resourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/listKeys?api-version=2018-03-01-preview
just checked how to convert azure rm to az powershell migration commands but dont know how to start exactly. Can some one help me on this

This site works best when you ask a specific, targetted question about a technical issue you have with code you’ve already written. Questions asking for general high-level advice often attract votes to close. If you can reword your question to include some code you’ve already written, with a description of the soecific issue (e.g. bug, error) you’re more likely to get a useful response. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details.

Azure you are making an HTTP connection.  HTTP contains a URL, HTTP Headers, and an HTTP Body.  Normally you have to use Authentication (OAUTH2) and a credential.  AZURE RNM most of the work is done inside an API.  Powershell you probably need to do more of the work inside your code.
